# How to I get the coordinates of a cell in a geotif?

Tags: python, gis, gdal

I have a tif with geoinformation. With gdal I can transform the raster file to an array (numpy).

How can I get the coordinates for one entry in that array?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the affine transformation matrix, which maps pixel coordinates to world coordinates. So for example, use the [affine](https://github.com/sgillies/affine) package. (There are other ways to do the same, using simple math.)

```
from affine import Affine
fname = '/path/to/raster.tif'
```

Here are two ways to get the affine transformation matrix, `T0`. E.g., using GDAL/Python:

```
from osgeo import gdal
ds = gdal.Open(path, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
T0 = Affine.from_gdal(*ds.GetGeoTransform())
ds = None  # close
```

E.g., using [rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio):

```
import rasterio
with rasterio.open(fname, 'r') as r:
    T0 = r.affine
```

The convention for the transform array as used by GDAL (`T0`) is to reference the pixel corner. You may want to instead reference the pixel centre, so it needs to be translated by 50%:

```
T1 = T0 * Affine.translation(0.5, 0.5)
```

And now to transform from pixel coordinates to world coordinates, multiply the coordinates with the matrix, which can be done with a simple function:

```
rc2xy = lambda r, c: T1 * (c, r)
```

Now, get the coordinates for a raster in the first row, second column (index `[0, 1]`):

```
print(rc2xy(0, 1))
```

Also, note that if you need to get the pixel coordinate from a world coordinate, you can use an inverted affine transformation matrix, `~T0`.

Comment: Sorry for the extremely delayed comment, but could you explain why the parameters of the lambda are inverted? r,c: (c,r) * T1. Shouldn't it be r,c: (r,c)*T1?

Comment: @jhc rows are aligned with the Y-direction and columns with X. So to keep X and Y directions aligned between pixel and coordinate spaces, the parameters are aligned. The function could have also been written in terms of (col, row) or `cr2xy = lambda c, r: (c, r) * T1`. But most array access (e.g. Numpy) use (row, col) ordering.

Comment: The canonical way to convert from `row, col` to `x, y` is using the multiplication operator. No need for the translation step or extra functions: `(0.5, 0.5) * affine`