# Know the geographic coordinates (longitude and latitude) of a particular pixel value in a GeoTIFF image

Tags: python, gdal, scikit-image, python-xarray, rasterio

Suppose I have a GeoTIFF image `img` with dimensions (1,3,3).

```
img = np.array([[[1.0, 2.3, 3.3],
                 [2.4, 2.6, 2.7],
                 [3.4, 4.2, 8.9]]])
```

I want to know the geographic coordinates(longitude and latitude) of the pixel whose value is 2.7 within the `img`.

Expected output:

```
coordinates = (98.4567, 16.2888)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/27913113 (the second part of the answer uses `rasterio`)

Comment: @mgc Thanks for sharing. However, it doesn't really answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is having the tag `rasterio` so i will consider you opened your geotiff with rasterio in that vein :

```py
import rasterio as rio
import numpy as np

dataset = rio.open('file.tif', 'r')
img = dataset.read(1)
# array([[1. , 2.3, 3.3],
#       [2.4, 2.6, 2.7],
#       [3.4, 4.2, 8.9]])
```

You have to retrieve the indexes (row and column) that correspond to the value you are looking for:

```py
cell_coords = np.where(img == 2.7)
# (array([1]), array([2]))
```

Then use the [`transform`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.io.html#rasterio.io.BufferedDatasetWriter.transform) attribute of your dataset (it contains the affine transformation matrix, using [`affine`](https://github.com/sgillies/affine) python package, allowing to map pixel coordinates to real world coordinates) like this :

```py
coordinates = rio.transform.xy(
    dataset.transform,
    cell_coords[0],
    cell_coords[1],
    offset='center',
)
# (98.4567, 16.2888) in your example
```

Comment: The idea worked. I made a small change, used ````rio.transform.xy````  to get the coordinates directly. Thanks!